# How can I pass a const to an other screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation, parameter-passing

I have an filtered Array "newAsanasAnfaenger" which I want to pass to another screen to use it for a slide show. How can I pass it to for exampe another class called "UebungenAnzeige"? How can I pass a whole array? Or is there a way to export two things from one file (e.g. class and const)?

```
render() {
   const {category} = this.props.route.params;
   const { navigation } = this.props;
   const newAsanasAnfaenger = asanas.filter(asana => asana.kategorie == category);
 
   return (
     <View>
      <View style={stylesUebungen.container2}>
       <FlatList
         data={newAsanasAnfanger}
         renderItem={this.renderEntry}
         keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
       />
       
        <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Auswahl')} />
       </View>
     </View>
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Auswahl', { myProp: newAsanasAnfaenger } )}
```

Then in your other component:

```
const { myProp } = this.props.route.params;
```

You can find more information about passing parameters to routes in the React Navigation documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Your second question seems unrelated to the first, but the answer is yes, you can export multiple things from one file. For example:

```
export const myVar = 1;
export function myFunc() { return true; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second question is related that I could simply export the array instead of passing it via the navigation. Is that right?

Comment: No, not necessarily. And, it's a pretty bad practice to pass around global state like that -- much more common and safe to pass via props or context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Please consider upvoting/accepting if this answers your original question